# The dialog box size cant show all the letter

Tags: interface, resolution

I am change the resolution of my pc.
The dialog somehow can't show all the information.
How to fix it...?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to 'File > Settings'. Look at the 'Interface' tab, and adjust the Scale. You probably want to adjust it down. Default is 1.00.

Remember to click on 'Save User Settings' after doing it, so the setting is saved until next time.

[image: A dialog box showing the interface tab of Blender 2.79b, where the scale input is hightlighted by a tooltip.]

Comment: The scale can change the interface, but it can't solve the problem.... It doesn't show all things in the dialog box.....